# How can I use HTML Canvas to draw a line relative to a point?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a certain design at random points, I am moving the pen with:

```
ctx.moveTo(Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1),Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
```

(If there is a better way of determining a random point between (0,0) and (300,300), I'm open to suggestions but now I want to use

```
ctx.lineTo(0,0)
```

in order to actually draw that line but that's only for absolute points, so how can I move the pen to a random point, then move, for example, 10 points up from that point?

Comment: You can keep track of the position using other variables.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir So instead of moving to a random point and then make lines relative, to instead, set 2 variables and move the pen to those variables and then do `ctx.lineTo(x=10,y+10);` or whatever I need (I'm new to JS so I'm just trying t figure it out)

Comment: Yes! Exactly!!!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thank you for that I just figured there had to be a way to make it relative, I have to do this several time so I figured it might save some space

Answer (score -2):

To generate the a new **random integer** each time you should set it to a variable that will call the method each time it is referenced. Also, more importantly, you need to define the points for the canvas to draw inside the `lineTo()` method and just set the starting coordinates in the `moveTo()` method.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var randPoint = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

ctx.lineTo(randPoint, randPoint);

ctx.stroke();
```